# How to replace href url without having all &amp; replaced by a &

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, href, replace

I'm trying to replace a few empty `href=""` statements with computed URL's on pageload.

The replacement string, however, contains several &amp's, which need to be in the href.

What ever I try, as soon as `setAttribute("href", url);` or `$(id).attr('href', url)` is used, all &amp's are replaced by a `&` and the links fail.

How can I prevent this from happening? I'm pretty sure any code that ends in `.href` or contains `href` is going through a translation stage and will all fail.

**You might have noticed that I've edited this message a lot of times because you simply cannot type a full '& a m p ;' in this box without it being translated to a '&' here too.**

Comment: How do you get the `url` variable?

Comment: Doesn't matter, it will always be a string and as soon there's an &amp; in it, it will become translated. If the same string is pasted into the href="" directly, there's no problem.

Comment: If you use *scripting* to write `&amp` to an attribute, then that will be in the attribute value *verbatim*. *That* is why the links fail. See also Gareth's excellent answer.

Comment: I have a ready made string-url which is correct. To get that string between the quotes of the href="" I tried, among other things  link.setAttribute("href", url);. The result is a href without the literal &amps in it and the Perl script it calls fails.

Answer (score 2):

Let's step back a bit, and think about this from the ground up. The escape sequence `&xxx;` is the way to embed "special characters" into an HTML document. To be clear, it is an **HTML** escape sequence.

This way of escaping characters is useful because it means characters can be placed into an ASCII file that would otherwise be impossible to embed.

For example, the Euro sign (`€`) can be embedded using a numeric code representing its Unicode codepoint `&#8364;`. Or, a non-breaking space can be embedded using its character entity name, `&nbsp;`. (Aside: these characters would be easier to embed in a UTF-8 file, with no escaping needed, but that's beside the point here)

Now, because this escape sequence always begins with an ampersand, it means that a bare ampersand in an HTML document is ambiguous - as the browser reads through the document it doesn't know if you want an actual ampersand or whether there's an HTML entity escape sequence coming up. To remove this ambiguity, if you want to embed an ampersand in an HTML document then you need to escape it.

Let me highlight that sentence: To remove this ambiguity, if you want to embed an ampersand ***in an HTML document*** then you need to escape it.

Because this escaping only applies to HTML documents, if you are writing Javascript in a `.js` file then this escape sequence is irrelevant to you. You can just drop your ampersands in unescaped and there's no problem. What it means is, your Javascript files can replace the URLs with bare ampersands, no `&amp;` needed.

As far as the browser is concerned, all of those URLs you write only contain bare ampersands. The escape sequence `&amp;` is only needed to **express those in HTML form**, as soon as the browser has read the HTML then that escape sequence is forgotten about.

I've repeated myself a few times here but that's because I've tried to make it as clear as possible.

Comment: But it's the HTLM href that NEEDS to pass on the &amps! But I need dynamic urls so cannot embed fixed hrefs.

Comment: @Avan Calm down and think about it. You are not writing HTML code here. In the simplest case you are setting the string property of an object.

Comment: It appears indeed that the replacements are not the culprit here. I had another issue at the same time and it looked like the string was causing the problem. I replaced the &amp;'s in the url-builder for regular ampersands and it now works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace `&` with `&amp;` in the url, prior to setting `href` property of an `a` tag.

```
var url = 'www.example.com?a=1&b=2'
url = url.replace(/\&/g, '&amp;')
$('a').attr('href', url)
```

Comment: No, the string already has &amp; in it and they get lost as soon as any href function is called. Simply calling $('a').attr('href', url) removes the &amps from the result in href="...".

Comment: It is the other way around because *scripting is not HTML*.